# Play Framework causing SIGSEGV fault on first page load with crud moduel

Tags: playframework, segmentation-fault, icedtea

Found this bug, which states the problem as well as I could.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/+bug/732707

The question is - are there any potential workarounds?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the bug report they mention they use IcedTea JVM, not Oracle's one. I've never had this problem with Oracle's, so the workaround: use Oracle's JVM.

Also, if you are using version 1.1.1 you should be aware there is a huge security hole, you should update to 1.2.3 ASAP. (latest 1.1.x may have it fixed, but I'm not sure)

Comment: Am using 1.2.3 - should have mentioned that in question.  Will try the Oracle JVM.