# fatal error on java in playframework production mode

Tags: java, playframework, segmentation-fault

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Play Framework application crashes on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697450/play-framework-application-crashes-on-linux)

I deployed my application to a linux ubuntu server. It works in Development mode. But it doesn't work in production mode. I tried on windows. It works. And i tried on Ubuntu Maveric, Natty, Oneric with 1.6.22 IcedTea and Oracle 1.7.03. But the result is same.

Finally i create an empty project. It works fine. Step by step i transfer all files. Everything goes ok except routes file. Then i commented all the lines in routes file. It works. Then step by step remove the comments. After 108 rules JVM gives sigsegv error.

I searched for non standart chars, EOL chars, tabs or spaces, and changed the route lines.
The result is same. After 108 rules (line count doesn't matter). My Server has 12 GB Ram. I used application with

java_args=-Xmx4096M property.

Comment: i found jvm_args property doesn't pass in production mode.

Comment: i tried "../play run --%production -Xms128m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:-UseCompressedOops -Xss24m" but the result is same.

Comment: Have you tried to add it in your application.conf: jvm.memory=-Xm4096M

Comment: yes i tried and it's the same with: "../play run --%production -Xms128m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:-UseCompressedOops -Xss24m"

Comment: checkout this similar question (though. i'm, sorry, no 'real' solution!) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697450/play-framework-application-crashes-on-linux

Comment: and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809896/play-framework-causing-sigsegv-fault-on-first-page-load-with-crud-moduel and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599520/play-framework-1-2-4-prod-precompiling-fails-with-java-7